# Python multiprocessing not creating new processes in Fedora

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm learning multiprocessing in Python 2.7. I tried the following code in both Windows 7 and Fedora 20.

**Code Sample**

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def worker():
    name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    print name, 'Starting'
    time.sleep(10)
    print name, 'Exiting'
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    worker_1=multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
    worker_2=multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
    
    worker_1.start()
    worker_2.start()
```

**In Windows-7** in the Task Manager I'm able to see 3 python processes running.

[image]

While **in Fedora-20** with the command `top | grep python`, I can see only one python process running.

[image]

Is it that in Linux, multiprocessing is not allowed by the operating system?

If a multiprocessing program will run like a normal program, then why one should prefer `multiprocessing` over `Threading`?

Comment: Instead of using `top` have you tried `ps aux | grep python`? And your worker run for only 10 seconds. Are you sure that you are checking within this 10 sec period?

Comment: @taskinoor With `ps aux | grep python` I'm able to see 3 python processes with 3 different PID. But `top` only shows 1. `top` shows dynamic real-time view of a running system, so I guess it does not depend on the wait time if I run `top` before running the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with Python, rather it is with the use of `top` command. By default, top shows only the processes that are fitted in a single screen. When your worker process are in sleep they takes low resources and falls behind. As a result they do not appear as a result of `grep`.

You can either use `ps aux` command to verify that workers got created or you can use `-b` option for `top` which is used to redirect output of `top`.

`top -b | grep python`

From [man top](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?top):

> -b : Batch mode operation
>           Starts top in 'Batch mode', which could be useful for sending out-
>           put from top to other programs or to a file.  In  this  mode,  top
>           will  not  accept input and runs until the iterations limit you've
>           set with the '-n' command-line option or until killed.